# Add number to vector repeatdly and duplicate vector

Tags: r, numbers, addition

I have a two value
3 and 5

and I make vector

```
num1 <- 3
num2 <- 12
a <- c(num1, num2)
```

I want add number(12) to vector "a" and
also I want to make new vector with repeat and append

like this:

```
3,12, 15,24, 27,36, 39,48 ....
```

repeat number "n" is 6

I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two methods in base R.

with `outer`, you could do

```
c(outer(c(3, 12), (12 * 0:4), "+"))
 [1]  3 12 15 24 27 36 39 48 51 60
```

or with `sapply`, you can explicitly loop through and calculate the pairs of sums.

```
c(sapply(0:4, function(i) c(3, 12) + (12 * i)))
 [1]  3 12 15 24 27 36 39 48 51 60
```

`outer` returns a matrix where every pair of elements of the two vectors have been added together. `c` is used to return a vector. `sapply` loops through 0:4 and then calculates the element-wise sum. It also returns a matrix in this instance, so `c` is used to return a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat generic function that takes as input your original vector `a`, the number to add `12`, and `n`,

```
f1 <- function(vec, x, n){
  len1 <- length(vec)
  v1 <- sapply(seq(n/len1), function(i) x*i)
  v2 <- rep(v1, each = n/length(v1))
  v3 <- rep(vec, n/len1)
  return(c(vec, v3 + v2))
}

f1(a, 12, 6)
#[1]  3 12 15 24 27 36 39 48

f1(a, 11, 12)
#[1]  3 12 14 23 25 34 36 45 47 56 58 67 69 78

f1(a, 3, 2)
#[1]  3 12  6 15
```

**EDIT**

If by `n=6` you mean 6 times the whole vector then,

```
f1 <- function(vec, x, n){
  len1 <- length(vec)
  v1 <- sapply(seq(n), function(i) x*i)
  v2 <- rep(v1, each = len1)
  v3 <- rep(vec, n)
  return(c(vec, v3 + v2))
}

f1(a, 12, 6)
#[1]  3 12 15 24 27 36 39 48 51 60 63 72 75 84
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rep` for repeating and `cumsum` for the addition:

```
n = 6
rep(a, n) + cumsum(rep(c(12, 0), n))
# [1] 15 24 27 36 39 48 51 60 63 72 75 84
```